# Laravel + Vue Page Redirection

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2

How can I redirect to a page when I try to create something that it has to be done in another page?

Example:

I created page that will ask the details for books and saved it to the database. The first page will ask the user to put the cover of the book, title and description. I used Vue Component for the page and axios to save it in the database. I used this code `window.location.href = "/create-book/"` to redirect to another page which will be the user can start writing and when he saved it, it will save on the current book he was making.

right now Im stuck in this

**Vue Component**

```
axios.post('/admin/saveBook', formData).then(function(result){
    // console.log(result.data)
    window.location.href = "/admin/write-book";
});
```

and In my controller I used this

**Controller**

```
return response()->json($book);
```

My goal is just to make a one whole page for writing the content of the book. Thanks!

Comment: Hey there, i'm not sure what the bug/hangup is from reading, could you please expand?

Comment: there's no bug, I just didnt know what will be the best way to do it

Answer (score 1):

You might look into using [Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/), specifically [Dynamic Route Matching](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html) and [Programmatic Navigation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html).

In your router, you'd have a dynamic path for your books.

```
routes: [
    {
        // dynamic segments start with a colon
        path: '/books/:id',
        name: 'book',
        component: Book
    }
]
```

Then in your component, you'd navigate to the book on creation.

```
axios.post('/admin/saveBook', formData).then(function(result) {
    this.$router.push({ name: 'book', params: { id: result.data.book.id }});
});
```

If you need info for the book when you navigate to it, you can either fetch it using the id when mounted or pass the book as a prop on navigation. See [Passing Props to Route Components](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#passing-props-to-route-components).